# Not able to append html inside dynamically loaded iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

**Index.html**

```
 <li>
       <a href="#" id="run">Run</a>
 </li>
    <iframe id="outputContentLoadContainer" src="" style="border:none"></iframe>
```

**output.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<style>
p{
   color: blue;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <p>hi I am new html.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
   $("#run").click(function(e) {    
            $("#outputContentLoadContainer").attr("src","index_output.html");
        $("#outputContentLoadContainer").contents().find("body").append('<p>Test</p>');     

  });
```

On click of Run I am appending `<p>Test</p>` to body of iframe html but it's only showing `<p>hi I am new html.</p>` why?

Comment: use $("#run").on('click',function(e) instead of $("#run").click(function(e)

Comment: @AlokDeshwal they are the same thing, `click()` is simply a shortcut for `on('click'...`

Comment: @ charlietfl 2 No I think they are not same thing where  ever i know .on method in jquery is used to bind the event where your html is created  dynamically

Comment: @AlokDeshwal the signature you provided does not do any delegation. That element must exist the way you have written it  ...  and yes`click()` uses `on()` internally so they are the same in this situation

Comment: @ charlietfl 29 Will you please check the following link
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is no different than using `document.ready` to allow the dom to load before running code... you need to let the iframe load also.

Think of it as an asynchronous operation .. there is time involved in getting the new page and time needed to render it

Try:

```
 $("#outputContentLoadContainer").on('load', function(){    
     $(this).contents().find("body").append('<p>Test</p>');
});

$("#run").click(function(e) {    
      $("#outputContentLoadContainer").attr("src","index_output.html");
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/s4t6aqBSfclgMmXzNfFb)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Jquery selector takes in a second param as a document Object in your example it would be `$('#outputContentLoadContainer').document`

Inserting a P tag

```
$('body', $('#outputContentLoadContainer').document).on('load',function(){
     $(this).append('<p>My Text in Dynamic iframe</p>');
});
```